# How can I ask the user for notification enabling a better visible way?

Tags: javascript

I've a problem. I've created a notification function in JS which sends notifications to the user. This is really important because of a chat. So what I've done is (regarding to the Google tutorial):

```js
function createBrowserNotification(title, message) {
  if (window.Notification) {
    if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
      new Notification(title, {
        body: message
      });
    } else {
      Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
        if (result === "granted") {
          new Notification(title, {
            body: message
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick"createBrowserNotification('Title', 'Message')">Click me!</button>
```

The problem is that there is no visible window that asks for a permission so the user might not see the little blocking message in the address bar in Chrome for example.

So does anyone has an idea how to deal with this a simple way? Maybe can I use `confirm()` here? If yes, how? Thanks for your help!

Comment: While it's possible to get a good answer for this question here, I'm wondering whether https://ux.stackexchange.com/ is a better suited place for this question.

Comment: have you defined `title`, `message` and `main_object`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, this is a WordPress thing. Ignore it.

Comment: ok, then cant reproduce it, if you blocked it once then it remembers it for that domain, you would have to go into settings or click the icon and allow it again.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry, I've removed the icon and added a working code example. What I mean is the initial requestPermission() call. There is no popup that makes the request visible so the user may not pay attention to it. I want to find a way around this. Thats the question.